# Структура модульной программы Java в Intellij

Tags: java, модули

Создаю модульную программу в ide Intellij, но при компиляции не видит пакеты из других модулей.

```
../filemanager
  Source/
    src/
      package
  Window/
    src/
      package
```

Такова структура программы. В дескрипторах модуля зависимости указаны(Source to Window), но пакеты не видны. В чем может быть проблема? И что за папка отмеченная как "source", в моем случае src? Без него пакеты создать невозможно. Модуль Source не виден и в дескрипторе модуля Window.
Добавлю:

```
module Source {
exports function to Window;
exports types to Window;
}
```

Добавляю префикс src. - не помогло

Comment: добавьте гредл в проект, тогда в зависимостях одного проекта (модуля), можно добавлять другие как зависимости

Comment: Intellij IDEA это всего лишь среда разработки (продвинутый текстовый редактор), она не умеет собирать проекты. Для того, чтобы создать многомодульное приложение необходимо использовать систему сборки Maven или Gradle.